# Is it possible to flash IMEI number of Nexus 5X without knowing its password

Tags: rooting, 6.0-marshmallow, nexus-5x

Phone was stolen from me and the next thing I did is to block the use of the phone in every possible way.

I would like to know that is it possible to flash IMEI number of Nexus 5X without knowing its password by rooting it.

The android developer options was disabled, the phone has a password lock and a fingerprint lock.

The phone was not rooted any time before.

Security updates were up to date.